# get all users from table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all users from users table and return response as JSON but I'm getting error of table is empty all the time even when there are data on the table.

My code:

```
<?php
include './include/DbHandler.php';

    $db = new DbHandler();
    $response = array();

    // fetching all users
    $result = $db->getAllUsers();

    if($result != NULL){
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["users"] = array();

        // looping through result and preparing users array
        while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["user_id"] = $user["id"];
            $tmp["first_name"] = $user["first_name"];
            $tmp["last_name"] = $user["last_name"];
            $tmp["mobile"] = $user["mobile"];
            $tmp["fcm_token"] = $user["token"];
            array_push($response["users"], $tmp);
        }
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "No users found on DB";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);    
?>
```

The `getAllUsers` function:

```
 public function getAllUsers(){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.mobile, u.token FROM users u");

    if($stmt->execute()){

        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $users = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->close();

            return $users;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you share the value of $stmt->num_rows ?

Comment: Try Select * from users where 1

Comment: I added : echo $stmt->num_rows(); on getAllUsers function before second if and got 0 !! although there are data on the table.

Comment: Does [`mysqli_stmt_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) give anything? Place it after the execute.

Comment: Yes. $this->conn = $db->connect();  The problem is with second if. if($stmt->num_rows > 0)

Comment: You should log or echo some specific error messages on each "else", for example on "if ($stmt->execute()){} else { echo 'Error on execute';}. Etc... Your query seems to be correct (but we don't know if there is a mistake on a column spelling as we don't know your table schema). I think that your main problem is that you don't include enough debug info into your code

Comment: Just a general FYI, you don't need `prepare()` here. Your query isn't passing user data, it's just asking for all the records in the table. You can simplify your function by using just `query()` instead

Comment: I added debug to getAllUsers function, and I'm returning NULL from if($stmt->num_rows > 0). Also printed the value of num_rows before that if and go 0. So problem is with first if.

Comment: @Khalil Jomaa check my answer. this will definitely resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.mobile, u.token FROM users u");

if($stmt->execute()){

    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        $users = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $users;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

in getAllUsers Function (add $stmt->store_result() before if(stmy_num-rows)

http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: OK. there is a progress. After adding $stmt->store_result(); I printed the value and got 2, but "return $users" looks like returns null.

Comment: you cannot close statement in a function getAllusers and then do $result->fetch_assoc after. Try to format result in the function (getAllUser) before close statement. excuse my english it is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

Instead of,

```
$stmt->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please refer this link, which is exact issue which you're facing after the tweak. Getting only 2 records,

[Fetch proper data returning only 2 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292919/fetch-row-with-pdo-and-relational-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will resolve your issue.

```
    public function getAllUsers(){

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.mobile, u.token FROM users u");
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->store_result();
            if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $col5);  
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $col5);
                }
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                return NULL;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
}
```

You have to use bind_result. please check the link why i use this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Answer (score 0):

something like this

public function getAllUsers(){

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.mobile, u.token FROM users u");

if($stmt->execute()){

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

        if($stmt->get_result() != NULL){
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["users"] = array();

            // looping through result and preparing users array
            while ($user = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["user_id"] = $user["id"];
                $tmp["first_name"] = $user["first_name"];
                $tmp["last_name"] = $user["last_name"];
                $tmp["mobile"] = $user["mobile"];
                $tmp["fcm_token"] = $user["token"];
                array_push($response["users"], $tmp);
            }
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "No users found on DB";
        }

        $stmt->close();

        return $response;
    } else {
        $stmt->close();
        return NULL;
    }
} else {
    $stmt->close();
    return NULL;
}
```

}